Automatically connection forticlient VPN in linux when it disconnects using Python script
So I need to have forti-client VPN connected all the time in a Fedora machine. Some times it disconnects and I need to connect it again automatically (right now is manual), I have an issue with expect and send, because it does not detect the input request and doesn't input the credentials and approve the connection.
So the flow goes like this:
Command: forticlient vpn connect {{VPN-NAME}} -u {{USER-NAME}}
Input 1: password:
Input 2: Confirm (y/n) [default=n]:Confirm (y/n) [default=n]:
Then it connects.
I built the next bash:
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set timeout -1

#Disconnect FortiClient VPN
forticlient vpn disconnect

# Set variables
set username {{USER-NAME}}
set password {{USER-PASSWORD}}

# Run the FortiClient VPN connection command

spawn "forticlient vpn connect {{VPN-NAME}} -u $username"
sleep 10
echo 'command executed'

# Expect password prompt and send password
expect "password:"
send "$password"\r

expect "Confirm (y/n) [default=n]:Confirm (y/n) [default=n]:"
send "y"

So not sure what is wrong but the echo 'command executed' goes after the inputs are required, so seems the expect executes after the inputs are requested. Not sure what I am doing wrong, it will be of great help if anyone knows how to fix it.
I am expecting that it connects automatically using bash, python or anything...but that I dont need to be manually reconnecting the VPN
Thanks in advance!

Using expect for this seem to be a not so good idea!

So what do you recommend?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : Why not? It looks like a reasonable choice to me...
